# Speech Recognition Microphone is not working

Tags: javascript

Can you please tell me why my microphone is not working  ?  When I made some correction in app.js file I can see microphone is blinking twice and then is death. I believe microphone is on. Any suggestion how to fix this problem ? Thank you

here is my code:

```
const msgEl = document.getElementById('msg')

window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition ||
window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition()


// start recognition
recognition.start();

function onSpeak(e) {
  const msg = e.results[0][0].transcript;
  console.log(msg)
  
}

recognition.addEventListener('result', onSpeak);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working, but by default, the recognition service is not continuous, it will end after a single result or timeout. So if you need continuous results you should set the property as `false`:

```
let recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition()
recognition.continuous = true;
```

But now the new results will be appended to the recognition list everytime there is a new result, so you will have to modify the way you print the results:

```
function onSpeak(e) {
    let msg = e.results[e.results.length-1][0].transcript;
    console.log(msg)
}
```

And if you do not want it to end on timeout if there is no activity, you may try this:

```
recognition.onend = function() {
    console.log('Speech recognition has stopped. Starting again ...');
    recognition.start();
}
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/continuous